# How to assign value with ES2016 async and nodejs

Tags: javascript, promise

I am writing with node.js and express to build an API when a user enters a URL on their address bar they make an xmlhttpreq to another site and the value is sent. Now this part works fine but I want to use that same information for further programming. So the code has to wait for the result and assign it to a variable. So I am trying out await and async. Below is my code.

```
app.get('/super', function(req, res){
res.send(console.log(config.options()));
 // config is imported this where the async code is
});
```

Config.js

```
module.exports = {
    options : async () =>{
                let super  = await getGas();
                return super
            },
}
var getGas = async ()=>{
provider = ether.providers.getDefaultProvider();
provider.getGasPrice().then(//provider.getGas is a promise
    function(gasPrice) {
        gasPriceString = gasPrice.toString();
        return gasPriceString;
    },
    function(error){
        var errorObj = JSON.parse(error.responseText);
    }
);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not returning the promise from `provider.getGasPrice()` in the anonymous  `async` function. You are also returning `gas` in the first function, but that doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. After that you aren't doing anything wrong so long as you are expecting `module.exports.options` to be a promise — not the final value. `async` functions return promises.

Comment: Ok thank you could you please type it out the correct answer. Yea sorry it was suppose to be super not gas. That is what i Dont't want I want the final value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `async`/`await`, you use it to replace `then`:

```
module.exports = {
    options: getGas,
};
async function getGas() {
    const provider = ether.providers.getDefaultProvider();
    try {
        const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice(); //provider.getGas() is a promise
//                       ^^^^
        const gasPriceString = gasPrice.toString();
        return gasPriceString;
    } catch(error) {
        var errorObj = JSON.parse(error.responseText);
        throw errorObj; // what else would you do with it here?
    }
}
```

And of course the whole thing is still asynchronous, so you need to respect that when calling the `options` function:

```
app.get('/super', async function(req, res){
    try {
        res.send(await config.options());
//               ^^^^^
    } catch(e) {
        // TODO: error handling
    }
});
```